# How to resolve a resource dependency of a Framework 4.8 class library referenced as a plugin from a .NET 5 host app?

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, .net-assembly

Given a .NET 5 plugin host application built per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/creating-app-with-plugin-support) example where the plugin is a .NET Framework 4.8 class library, how do you resolve a plugin’s dependency on a Framework resource such as System.Web.Services without including it as a static dependency to the host app?

Comment: In theory you could create a wrapper for the plugin that targets .NET 5, with a static dependency to System.Web.Services.  However, if your class library is not targeting .NET Standard, this might not be advisable since some dynamically loaded assemblies may not be available, which is somewhat incompatible with the plugin ideology.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately the plugin utilizes a SDK which does not target .NET Standard.